# Remote Debugging .net

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging, remote-debugging

I've read all related remote debug entries here and couldn't find an answer to my problem. I've trying to setup remote debugging to test a console app. 
Dev Machine - Vista, VS 2008
Remote Machine - Win 2008

I've followed the steps in [this article](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-to-get-Remote-Debugging-work-properly.aspx) to configure it and I'm stuck with the following error when I try to list processes in remote machine under 'Attach to Process'.

"The remote procedure call failed and did not execute".

But in my remote machines 'Remote Debug Monitor' I see that the dev machine connection was established.

Can anyone provide me with any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I run into this problem the first thing I do is disable the firewall on both computers.  Firewall problems are the most common issue I run into with remote debugging and it's best to eliminate that problem from the start.

Do take care to turn the firewall back on when you're done diagnosing the problem :).